# Mercurial: how to display message to clients

Tags: mercurial

I am planning to move the central repo, I want to display an error message to anyone that is trying to use: hg pull and tell them the new location of the repo. I wrote a hook that uses events, but none of the events are triggering if someone uses: hg pull

pulling over HTTP 
any ideas??

Comment: What connection are they pulling over? HTTP? SSH? local file system?

Answer (score 5):

ssg's answer is extremely easy and here is one more easy way based on [preoutgoing hook](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/hgrc).  You need to put this in your `.hg/hgrc` of your remote repository.

```
[hooks]
preoutgoing = echo "Repository moved to <url>"
```

Comment: If there are changes in your repo then it works, but when there isn't any changes then preoutgoing does not work, does not triger. Basically we want to notify the user as soon as they do ANY interaction with the repo that it moved to a new location.

Comment: So add a new change.  Something like "hg tag exists_only_to_trigger_pre_outgoing"  No one will ever get that tag if you make sure the hook returns non-zero (the pull will be aborted)

Comment: I didn't know about `preoutgoing` hook. That's a better approach but make sure you add a "nonzero exit code" to hook to fail the pull request. That way users who miss the message will be forced to be aware of the situation.

Comment: that worked fine using preoutgoing hook. Now I have a different issue. If a user tries to hg clone <ur> then they gets:bort: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error
instead of my msg about repo being moved. Any ideas?

Comment: @user2751475 How exactly do you host your repository?

Comment: @user2751475 What web server do you use?