# Mercurial repo moved message

Tags: mercurial

I am planning to move the central repo to a different URL. I created a hook using preoutgoing event to notify the user when they try to push , pull or clone using the old url that the URL moved to a new location. EVerything is working fine except in the case when a user tries to do hg clone  he gets:

abort: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error

instead of my message. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mercurial: how to display message to clients](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641374/mercurial-how-to-display-message-to-clients)